# Pandas DataFrame.Apply output format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

Have questions concerning the output of `apply()` method in python `pandas.DataFrame`

#### Q1 -

Why does this function returns a `pandas.DataFrame` **with the same format** as the input (`pandas.DataFrame`) when `apply` function returns an `array` with the same shape as input?.

For instance

```
foo = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]],columns=['a','b'])
foo.apply(lambda x: [np.min(x)/2,np.max(x)/2], axis='index')
```

code will return:

```
       a        b   
0   min(a)/2   min(b)/2  
1   max(a)/2   max(b)/2
```

#### Q2 -

For some reason I would like to output a `pandaq.Series` of arrays instead:

```
0   [min(a)/2, max(a)/2]  
1   [min(b)/2, max(b)/2]
...
```

I have tried `reduce=True` without success.
Then, **How should I do?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to avoid `apply` where `numpy` operations are possible.

In this case, there are at least a couple of alternatives. Below are examples with benchmarking. As you can see, the closer you move to `numpy`, the better the results.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

foo = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]],columns=['a','b'])

foo = pd.concat([foo]*10000, ignore_index=True)

def dark(df):
    return df.apply(lambda x: tuple([np.min(x)/2,np.max(x)/2]), axis=1)

def jp1(df):
    return [tuple([np.min(x)/2,np.max(x)/2]) for x in foo[['a', 'b']].values]

def jp2(df):
    arr = foo[['a', 'b']].values
    return list(zip(*(np.min(arr, axis=1)/2, np.max(arr, axis=1)/2)))

%timeit dark(foo)  # 4.95s
%timeit jp1(foo)   # 298ms
%timeit jp2(foo)   # 4.68ms
```

Of course, `dark()` returns a `pd.Series`, but `pandas` lets you assign via a list.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the ndim of the resultant array is 2. If you see the main code of `apply` [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/3a7f956c30528736beaae5784f509a76d892e229/pandas/core/frame.py#L4280) if the ndim is 2 then DataFrame constructor is applied.

```
    #Main Code
    ...
    # TODO: mixed type case
    if result.ndim == 2:
        return DataFrame(result, index=self.index, columns=self.columns)
    else:
        return Series(result, index=self._get_agg_axis(axis))
```

If you want the result as series then use something like `tuple` instead of a list i.e

```
foo = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]],columns=['a','b'])
foo.apply(lambda x: tuple([np.min(x)/2,np.max(x)/2]), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    (0.5, 1.0)
1    (1.5, 2.0)
dtype: object
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer, it works with tuple instead of array.